# Laravel WebSockets pusher in AWS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, laravel-8

I create a socket app and it works fine locally
but when I want to test if it will be working in AWS it gives me this error

****Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException
Pusher error: {"error":"Unknown app id `12345` provided."}.****

I don't know  does the setting will be different on AWS
or it is a cache issue

this is my sitting

**brodcasting.php**

```
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            //'useTLS' => true,
            //'forceTLS'=>true,
            'encrypted' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'=>'6001',
            'scheme'=> 'http',
            //'curl_options' => [
           //     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
          //      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
          //    ]
        ],
    ],
```

**websoket.php**

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        //'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
        //'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
        
    ],
],
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
 window.Echo = new Echo({
 broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
 //cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
 //forceTLS: true,
 wsHost: window.location.hostname,
 wsPort: 6001,
 forceTLS: false,
 disableStats: true, });
```

Comment: It simply says the error. You should provide a valid `PUSHER_APP_ID`.

Comment: Because I am using WebSocket server from Beyond what I understate the server replace the pusher so I need to make my own key and id for the pusher, not using the key that pusher website provides to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used my name and it worked

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=fredrickshayo
PUSHER_APP_KEY=fredrickshayo
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=fredrickshayo
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you might need to change the `'host'` in your `broadcasting.php` to point to whatever IP/domain your laravel-websockets is running on

Comment: after I change it  give me ( 504 Gateway Time-out )